How to call PGSQL/PostgreSQL stored procedure from Jitterbit?
How to call PGSQL/PostgreSQL stored procedure from Jitterbit? Can anyone provide sample code please?
I have written this code, but it doesn't work and throws an error:
CallStoredProcedure("<TAG>Targets/Database/TestingPGSQL</TAG>", "Your SP Name", resultSet,
            "ImportedbySSM",'3784',"ImportedbySSM",'2056',swv_refcur);


Failed to test expression: CallStoredProcedure failed to execute call "SPNAME".
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function SPNAME(character varying, integer, character varying, integer, character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 8


One thing that stands out is that your Database connection in the first argument is incorrect. It should be a Database endpoint and should look something like CallStoredProcedure("<TAG>endpoint:database/The Database Name</TAG>", "Your SP Name", resultSet);.

Thank for reply Ashvan. Can you please provide example ?

What sort of example are you looking for? The answer has an example of how CallStoredProcedure would be called with the correct format of the Database endpoint.
